# Magento Model not loading

Tags: magento

I'm trying to create a simple module to magento. I've created my controller, my routings but for some reason I can't get access to my model. As far as I know, it's not even loaded.

I get no error message, and the model object isn't created.

What might be causing this?

Here's some information:

Controller:

```
class MyVendor_MyModule_IndexController extends Mage_Core_Controller_Front_Action
{

    public function pingAction(){

        $model = Mage::getModel('mymodule/mymodule');       
        echo "<pre>" . print_r($model->load(1),true);

    }
}
```

Model tree view:

> ```
> MyVendor
> -MyModule
> -- controllers
> ---- IndexController.php
> -- Model
> ---- Mysql4
> -------- MyModule.php
> -------- MyModule
> ---------------- Collection.php
> ---- MyModule.php
> -- etc
> ---- config.xml
> ```

config.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<config> 
    <modules>
        <MyVendor_MyModule>
            <version>0.0.1</version>
        </MyVendor_MyModule>
    </modules>
    <frontend>
        <routers>
            <mymodule>
                <use>standard</use>
                <args>
                    <module>MyVendor_MyModule</module>
                    <frontName>mymodule</frontName>
                </args>
            </mymodule>
        </routers>   
    </frontend>
    <global>
        <models>
            <mymodule>
                <class>MyVendor_MyModule_Model</class>
                <resourceModel>mymodule_mysql4</resourceModel>
            </mymodule>
            <mymodule_mysql4>
                <class>MyVendor_MyModule_Model_Mysql4</class>
                <entities>
                    <mymodule>
                        <table>mymodule_table</table>
                    </mymodule>
                </entities>
            </mymodule_mysql4>
        </models>
        <resources>
                    <mymodule_setup>
                        <setup>
                                <module>MyVendor_MyModule</module>
                        </setup>
                        <connection>
                                <use>core_setup</use>
                        </connection>
                    </mymodule_setup>
                    <mymodule_setup>
                        <connection>
                                <use>core_write</use>
                        </connection>
                    </mymodule_setup>
                    <mymodule_setup>
                        <connection>
                                <use>core_read</use>
                        </connection>
                    </mymodule_setup>
            </resources>
    </global>
</config>
```

And in my Model I've got a simple:

```
class MyVendor_MyModule_Model_Mysql4_MyModule extends Mage_Core_Model_Mysql4_Abstract
{
    public function _construct()
    {   
        $this->_init('mymodule/mymodule', 'id');
    }
}
```

Comment: What's the code you're running to access your model?

Comment: Random Debugging Tips: What does the call to $model->load return? (var_dump instead of print_r).   Can you instantiated your model class directly?  ($o = new MyVendor_MyModule_Model_MyModel;)  Look in Mage_Core_Model_Config::getGroupedClassName and try to figure out why Magento can't read a class name from your config.

Comment: @AlanStorm : when I do $model->load I get the error "Fatal error: Call to a member function load() on a non-object in..".. when I instantiate my model directly, i get the same message but in Mage/Core/Model/Abstract.php on line 225. The getGroupedClassName returns string(6) "Mage__"

Comment: You have a typo somewhere in config.xml or your config.xml isn't being loaded by the system.  Debug in getGroupedClassName and determine the path where Magento is looking in the global configuration. Compare that to the path in your own XML file.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Depending on platform, `Mage::getModel('mymodule/mymodule');` may be case sensitive when looking for the file to load (namely that it should be `Mage::getModel('myModule/myModule');` given your folder structure and naming)

Check what get_class(Mage::getModel('mymodule/mymodule')) returns.  Is it the classname of your class?  If not then you're not even making an instance of your object.  Check the camel-casing earlier, and that you actually have a file /MyVendor/MyModule/Model/MyModule.php (which you didn't include the code from).

If you have an instance of you class, you probably don't have any rows in the DB to support it.  So ->load(1); isn't going to do anything.

Comment: case sentitive naming was in fact the problem here. everything works fine now. thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Did you add in app/etc/modules/MyVendor_MyModule.xml and are you sure there are no typo errors for that.
If you find your module in admin then that confirms your module is registered.

You are extending a controller.So what was done to override core controller.